# Can you help me identify the set this dark grey pedestal sub-assembly belongs to?

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help me identify the set this sub-assembly belongs to?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you positive this is a sub-assembly from an actual LEGO set, or is it just someone's custom built? I have looked at some of the combinations, and I wasn't able to find a set that has all the parts in this assembly.

Comment: Are you sure it is Lego?
The lettering on the studs doesn't look like the word "Lego" to me.

Comment: Zooming in on the first image shows the logo pretty clearly. May well not be a single set though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is from [70114-1: Sky Joust](https://brickset.com/sets/70114-1/Sky-Joust)

[image]
[image]